# How to select all values with a distinct subset in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, distinct

I have a table in Oracle, which has many columns. 5 of them is a key combination which needs to be unique. others are what they are. Also I need to perform a join with another table.
What I'm trying to achieve :

table ost:

id_shop, ean, kol, cena1, cena2, cena3, nei, art, asize, procent, scan, partno //the last 5 must be distinct in a combo, the first 7 are as is.

Also I want to select only those from table ost which are in a join like this:

```
join s_shop on ost.id_shop = s_shop.shopid
where s_shop.landid = 'RU' 
and ost.id_shop != 'S888' || 'S999'
and ost.art not in (select art from osttek)
```

I want to select this to later insert into the table where the primary key is those 5 cols (hence unique combo). I tried joining all with selecting only combo from self, but somehing is wrong. Also where should I perform the join with s_shop then?
thanks

ost

```
id_shop, ean, kol, cena1, cena2, cena3, nei, art, asize, procent, scan, partno
1        123   22    10     9      8   gh2y2 3dw    40      0     n22s    b22w2
1         143  12    6     3      2   b23h   3dw    40      0     n22s    b22w2
2        111   21    11    4      7   gdd2   32w    30      10    n22s    b22w2
2        222  11    12     5      8   bo0h   32k    30      20    n22s    b22w2
1        222  11    12     5      8   bo0h   32k    30      20    n22s    b22w2
S999      222  11    12     5      8   7yff   31s    31      21    n21s    b22w2
```

as you see first two rows have the same key combo. if we suppose that in s_shop 1 maps to landid 'RU' and 2 to 'BU', then i need only the first row (if art 3dw is not in all arts of table osttek)
imagine art in table osttek are like:

```
table osttek:

ART
34hd,
32ej,
490d;

table s_shop

landid shopid
RU       1
BU       2 
BZ       S999
```

I need a query which would return rows:

```
1        123   22    10     9     8  gh2y2 3dw    40      0     n22s    b22w2
1        222  11    12     5      8   bo0h   32k    30      20    n22s    b22w2
```

Comment: Some example data with expected result would be of help...

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve]

Comment: Added info about what rows i need

Comment: Great, please spend some more time and add expected results from that data...

Comment: Ready, i added info about more tables and my desired output

Comment: In your example, why did you select the first row instead of the second? (I understand you only want one of them because the key matches, but how do you pick which one?)

Comment: good question! It's just that I really need to copy the key columns only. I just wanted to transfer everything but I guess I will have to add the non-key values manualy. Thanks, i guess question may be close

Comment: Okay. You know you can use `COUNT OVER` to find the duplicate keys?

Comment: What determines **later insertion** ( eg. *ordering rule for the rows* in order to eliminate ) ?

Comment: Actually i wanted to just select the key combo, I just saw that other columns have similar names to the destination table that's why i wanted to try them. What I wanted is select all rows from ost where the corresponsing id shop translates to 'ru' and where all the key combos don't repeat and where there are no rows where the art field is equal to any of the art fields of the osttek table